# Div ocupando todo o height da página

Tags: css, modal

Então moçada, to desenvolvendo um sistema aqui que abre um modal para editar umas informações... O modal abre uma DIV fundo que só pega o tamanho da tela, se eu rolar pra baixo essa div fundo fica cortada.

Vou postar imagens para entenderem.

Esse é o modal quando eu abro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E fica assim depois que eu rolo a barra:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Queria que essa div minha acompanhasse todo o tamanho da página! Alguém teria uma ideia ai para me ajudar?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

além desse truque de deixar o html e o body 100%:

```
html, body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

o seu elemento precisa ser um position: absolute a partir do body.
exemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
<style>
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
p { margin-bottom: 10px; }
html, body {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.content { max-width: 1060px; margin: 0 auto; }
#overlay {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="overlay"></div>

  <div class="content">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis veritatis iure soluta rem earum ab tempora iusto laboriosam sed temporibus illo optio hic, totam labore deleniti dignissimos excepturi alias consequatur.</p>
    <p>Laborum, impedit aspernatur ipsam enim. Optio, corrupti possimus, praesentium voluptatem sint quos accusamus eligendi iusto rerum amet sequi! Voluptatem consequatur beatae officiis magnam accusantium sunt laborum labore in accusamus minus?</p>
    <p>Minima cum sit dolore modi. Mollitia adipisci eos accusantium voluptatem voluptatibus rerum vero explicabo sed animi repudiandae vel dolore culpa, perspiciatis accusamus eum fugiat sit praesentium error odio porro? Quas.</p>
    <p>Ad reprehenderit fuga atque. Laboriosam harum iure, consectetur reiciendis dolores quisquam, expedita aut! Nisi natus ipsum reprehenderit odio doloremque, culpa accusantium laudantium error amet recusandae, cupiditate quidem? Ipsum, praesentium, dolorem.</p>
    <p>Unde laudantium, mollitia quae ex eveniet cupiditate, distinctio doloribus facilis hic est nesciunt eligendi quasi non nostrum voluptate veritatis dignissimos, laboriosam nobis vitae. Voluptatibus ipsum animi in assumenda voluptatum doloremque.</p>
    <p>Minima unde eligendi itaque hic eos sint ut reprehenderit cupiditate dolore, doloremque quod maiores, tempora sequi debitis. Quis, reiciendis sint, perspiciatis doloremque dolorem cupiditate, quasi nulla minus, alias consectetur voluptate.</p>
    <p>Vero numquam autem reprehenderit ducimus laborum accusantium eaque illum, dicta ullam doloremque! Culpa perferendis quas expedita natus accusantium beatae, odit nam modi, sapiente assumenda minus, distinctio incidunt, doloribus adipisci! Hic!</p>
    <p>Soluta mollitia eligendi voluptatum labore natus, facilis, maiores tenetur facere nobis consectetur, autem numquam aut repellendus laudantium. Accusantium, architecto quis deserunt, qui quo, dolor optio est quisquam ut aspernatur saepe!</p>
    <p>Facilis reiciendis inventore quibusdam ullam itaque tempore porro consequatur, cumque qui rerum reprehenderit libero voluptate doloribus atque perspiciatis harum, dolor repellendus vero accusamus iusto. Harum explicabo facilis pariatur reprehenderit quibusdam.</p>
    <p>Minus numquam nisi praesentium, quos doloribus? Ipsam distinctio, consequuntur quis. Odio vero est placeat, doloribus quod, dicta voluptate consectetur pariatur harum magni mollitia facilis nobis unde, saepe autem quasi inventore.</p>
    <p>Consequuntur facere est deserunt illum voluptate aliquid ullam odio tempora eius, iste reiciendis consequatur repellat magni nemo dolore, tempore eveniet eaque enim ex nam delectus modi quae esse. Voluptates, facilis.</p>
    <p>Architecto sint, dolor quisquam quidem enim porro molestias. Cum odio, amet, blanditiis ea facere fugiat nisi esse nihil, aliquam quibusdam harum debitis mollitia excepturi eum. Quidem, accusamus. Asperiores, velit culpa.</p>
    <p>Repellendus expedita doloremque quis facere magni, voluptas voluptatem nobis at dolor quasi velit, commodi dignissimos eos quia, quod. Porro similique assumenda ea, possimus. Delectus, omnis cupiditate vero tenetur aspernatur quam.</p>
    <p>Modi alias nihil at qui rem! Quas perferendis, doloribus. Sunt aut deserunt, natus minima a amet dolore voluptate eligendi placeat! Laudantium laboriosam doloribus quibusdam quaerat optio dolorum minima eum totam?</p>
    <p>Eaque suscipit blanditiis itaque, facere iste, quos voluptatum delectus necessitatibus nihil hic veniam dolores voluptatibus reiciendis, nobis sapiente minus perferendis exercitationem ullam dolorem officia consequatur. Sunt totam aspernatur quisquam asperiores.</p>
    <p>Similique vero, laudantium explicabo rerum. Nobis id aliquid vel perspiciatis explicabo et hic numquam commodi esse incidunt consequatur necessitatibus, quod, officiis! Rem ipsum dolore facilis, beatae quam hic culpa quis!</p>
    <p>Nam fuga rem magni corrupti cum, corporis ducimus iste ex unde cupiditate ipsum voluptate maxime doloremque minus rerum similique laboriosam optio veritatis sapiente. Fugit harum excepturi temporibus, sint nam, dolorem?</p>
    <p>Harum quis, dolores explicabo sint, ratione aperiam earum quo sapiente soluta optio quae necessitatibus autem et doloribus nemo esse numquam perferendis repudiandae, nostrum saepe velit nam? Dolorum deserunt ex ipsa!</p>
    <p>Temporibus tempore nulla laborum aliquid? A, ipsa, architecto. Recusandae veniam quisquam nisi obcaecati laudantium adipisci mollitia, sequi iusto est inventore, ad non. Porro, distinctio itaque accusamus blanditiis omnis autem, nostrum.</p>
    <p>Veritatis voluptate, impedit reiciendis, eius debitis ex at sit id error accusantium repellat libero non repudiandae ipsa labore consectetur ducimus autem dignissimos accusamus voluptatibus dolorem. Perspiciatis porro rem officia architecto?</p>
    <p>Sapiente illo autem laudantium laboriosam fugit pariatur voluptatibus quod nostrum, doloribus perspiciatis aspernatur error quos dolorem suscipit. Autem adipisci ullam ab accusamus, illo minima! Voluptatum ea praesentium quas nostrum consequuntur.</p>
    <p>Possimus eum optio exercitationem adipisci animi dignissimos earum sed ab, cumque, rerum doloremque mollitia vitae autem, nulla! Reiciendis minus, eius nulla. Odit quae itaque quam aut, iure voluptatum, iusto aliquid.</p>
    <p>Explicabo fugit, non, quasi odio quod tempore magni dicta consequatur possimus incidunt, provident aliquid! Nesciunt et accusamus aliquam repellat debitis veritatis numquam corrupti ullam ipsum ipsam, voluptatibus officiis unde pariatur.</p>
    <p>Porro neque omnis voluptas dolorum atque et ipsum ratione rem autem necessitatibus vitae magnam voluptatibus, molestias vero eum officiis, laboriosam possimus hic doloremque dolor sit. Commodi animi fugit temporibus saepe.</p>
    <p>Explicabo neque, mollitia hic, laboriosam eligendi eaque repellat omnis! Culpa, odit recusandae. Sunt atque exercitationem, deserunt beatae nesciunt iure vel pariatur aspernatur soluta rem aut sequi expedita eligendi. Eligendi, animi?</p>
    <p>Totam mollitia placeat dignissimos commodi magni quaerat, voluptatem animi ex hic fuga doloremque distinctio modi fugit, blanditiis numquam delectus facilis culpa, ipsam itaque minima. Nihil rerum dicta repudiandae repellendus ducimus.</p>
    <p>Praesentium suscipit, voluptatum optio cum doloribus sit! Quam eaque, fuga, accusantium ad inventore ipsa voluptatum repellendus sint itaque nobis tempore maxime perferendis nemo minima dolorum, aliquam eius officiis nisi quaerat.</p>
    <p>Quaerat sapiente, est ipsam quas, ex eos cum, ipsum modi sint debitis officia at. Officiis, provident voluptate. Totam molestiae esse sed provident, veniam ducimus consequatur impedit, beatae eveniet distinctio hic.</p>
    <p>Saepe, accusantium sint, iusto eveniet vero perspiciatis voluptatibus maxime voluptate est quibusdam ab! Enim accusamus quis facere, dicta sequi, ratione vero eos mollitia, excepturi iste vel aliquid reiciendis! Unde, asperiores.</p>
    <p>Atque accusantium quidem possimus sit molestias ullam praesentium quaerat fuga unde iusto optio, aperiam deserunt voluptatem ducimus provident rerum dolorum vel! Laudantium velit veritatis quis cum sequi suscipit, mollitia expedita!</p>
    <p>Explicabo modi et voluptatibus accusantium in dolorum, doloribus ipsa ipsum doloremque id neque itaque, animi magnam vero reprehenderit quae sunt ducimus expedita incidunt sint sequi consequuntur totam minus. Architecto, ad!</p>
    <p>Delectus beatae facere eaque. Praesentium earum inventore molestias quia iusto! Quidem consequuntur maiores, omnis veritatis iste beatae assumenda eius, at sequi dolores, blanditiis consectetur qui soluta reiciendis distinctio facere ducimus!</p>
    <p>Laudantium rerum consectetur iusto quod reprehenderit non, aliquam nobis cumque esse animi ducimus impedit dolorem placeat officia pariatur dolores sed ipsa unde, ipsam itaque deserunt? Odit velit dolorum similique quos.</p>
    <p>Nobis vitae quisquam quis eos commodi mollitia, possimus veritatis voluptas! Sint ad possimus ab odio repudiandae laudantium et nobis veritatis facere iste voluptates hic, sed ipsum voluptatibus enim, blanditiis eius!</p>
    <p>Labore modi, explicabo. Quas quaerat aspernatur illo, explicabo maiores quos praesentium, in recusandae neque alias! Voluptates saepe, ratione maiores perspiciatis iusto obcaecati architecto quasi. Architecto beatae quasi corporis debitis consequatur!</p>
    <p>Quo facere amet ipsam dolore fugit veritatis accusantium iste earum laudantium fuga, iure incidunt debitis aut, placeat ullam necessitatibus. Voluptatum explicabo perferendis, voluptas quidem praesentium quibusdam quaerat possimus in architecto.</p>
    <p>Perspiciatis nam maxime facere pariatur, nihil architecto illum laboriosam hic neque non voluptatem sit, ipsum quasi est nemo ut, mollitia cupiditate! Assumenda laudantium rem quam labore nostrum, tempore reprehenderit eos!</p>
    <p>Nihil tenetur ipsam quidem sint, fugiat doloremque voluptatibus autem esse vel, quam quo provident at saepe, nemo veritatis ab labore ex nulla excepturi laborum. Excepturi magni corrupti ipsam, quae id!</p>
    <p>Aut in atque laudantium soluta voluptates ut non dolores, cupiditate corrupti facere beatae velit iste deserunt inventore quibusdam quisquam reprehenderit, laboriosam aspernatur earum, eveniet, eligendi? Ipsa perspiciatis aspernatur eligendi. Mollitia?</p>
    <p>Sunt debitis eos quasi hic sapiente doloribus cum maxime cumque, nobis at impedit nulla quam nostrum tempora fugit, maiores perspiciatis iure! Blanditiis reiciendis alias saepe officia dolorem illum dignissimos aperiam!</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tens algumas maneiras de fazer isso, ou limitas o tamanho da modal e colocas um scroll dentro da mesma, por exemplo:

```
height: 100px;
overflow: scroll;
```

Desta forma poderias até colocar um: `position: fixed;` na tua css e definir o tamanho em relação ao topo `top: 50px;`, por exemplo.

Outra coisa que podes fazer é colocar o teu background fixo, de forma a quando fizeres scroll down o background do fundo da modal não ficar a meio e dessa forma não tens problemas se alguém fizer scroll.

```
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
```

Espero ajudar, se achares que esta não é a melhor solução, pedia que colocasses aqui a maneira como estás a fazer as div's para te poder ajudar mais um pouco.

Cumps,

Answer (score -1):

Tem que se atentar como o seu elemento de fundo esta se comportando, por exemplo se esta com `height: 100%` então nunca ultrapassará este tamanho e por isso existe o corte, você pode resolver deixando o elemento de fundo `position: fixed` e habilitar o scrol `overflow-y: auto`

ou definir a altura mínima de 100% `min-height: 100%` assim quando seu conteúdo ultrapassar a altura mínima ele vai se ajustando conforme a quantidade de conteúdo.

Answer (score -1):

Não entendi bem, você quer deixar ocupando 100% da página?

Se for tente o código:

```
.suadiv{
   heigth:100%;
}
```